# Media query not working in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, media-queries

This media query code works in Chrome but is not working in Firefox Developer.

But if I open Web Tools in Firefox and add a line break anywhere in the stylesheet then it works.

```css
    #Line_98 {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: rgba(112,112,112,1);
        stroke-width: 1px;
        stroke-linejoin: miter;
        stroke-linecap: butt;
        stroke-miterlimit: 4;
        shape-rendering: auto;
    }
    .Line_98 {
        overflow: visible;
        position: absolute;
        width: 600px;
        height: 1px;
        left: 0px;
        top: 143.5px;
        transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    }
    #Line_99 {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: rgba(112,112,112,1);
        stroke-width: 1px;
        stroke-linejoin: miter;
        stroke-linecap: butt;
        stroke-miterlimit: 4;
        shape-rendering: auto;
    }
    .Line_99 {
        overflow: visible;
        position: absolute;
        width: 600px;
        height: 1px;
        left: 0px;
        top: 195.5px;
        transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    }
    #Show_when_view_less_than_line_ {
        display: none;
        left: 46px;
        top: 161px;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 255px;
        height: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: rgba(160,160,160,1);
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }

    /** show when less than width */
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .Show_when_view_less_than_line_ {
        display: block !important;
      }
    }

    #Show_when_view_more_than_line_ {
        display: none;
        left: 46px;
        top: 222px;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 299px;
        height: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: rgba(160,160,160,1);
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }

    /** show when more than width */
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .Show_when_view_more_than_line_ {
        display: block !important;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="Responsive_Parts_VI">
    <svg class="Line_98" viewBox="0 0 600 1">
        <path id="Line_98" d="M 0 0 L 600 0">
        </path>
    </svg>
    <svg class="Line_99" viewBox="0 0 600 1">
        <path id="Line_99" d="M 0 0 L 600 0">
        </path>
    </svg>
    <div id="Show_when_view_less_than_line_" class="Show_when_view_less_than_line_">
        <span>Show when view less than line width</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Show_when_view_more_than_line_" class="Show_when_view_more_than_line_">
        <span>Show when view more than line width</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm going to see if this works in the StackOverflow view.

To test resize the browser in Firefox.

Here is the full page code (you can save locally):

https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#9ioj8td2o5o6gjygd7com3

Here is the full page code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Media</title>
<style id="applicationStylesheet" type="text/css">
    .mediaViewInfo {
        --web-view-name: Media;
        --web-view-id: Media;
        --web-scale-on-resize: true;
        --web-refresh-for-changes: true;
        --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
    }
    :root {
        --web-view-ids: Media;
    }
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
    }
    #Media {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        --web-view-name: Media;
        --web-view-id: Media;
        --web-scale-on-resize: true;
        --web-refresh-for-changes: true;
        --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
    }
    #Line_99 {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: rgba(112,112,112,1);
        stroke-width: 1px;
        stroke-linejoin: miter;
        stroke-linecap: butt;
        stroke-miterlimit: 4;
        shape-rendering: auto;
    }
    .Line_99 {
        overflow: visible;
        position: absolute;
        width: 600px;
        height: 1px;
        left: 0px;
        top: 195.5px;
        transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    }
    #Show_when_view_less_than_line_ {
        display: none;
        left: 46px;
        top: 161px;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 255px;
        height: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: rgba(160,160,160,1);
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }

    /** show when less than width */
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .Show_when_view_less_than_line_ {
        display: block !important;
      }
    }

    #Show_when_view_more_than_line_ {
        display: none;
        left: 46px;
        top: 222px;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 299px;
        height: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: rgba(160,160,160,1);
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }

    /** show when more than width */
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .Show_when_view_more_than_line_ {
        display: block !important;
      }
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Media">
    <svg class="Line_99" viewBox="0 0 600 1">
        <path id="Line_99" d="M 0 0 L 600 0">
        </path>
    </svg>
    <div id="Show_when_view_less_than_line_" class="Show_when_view_less_than_line_">
        <span>Show when view less than line width</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Show_when_view_more_than_line_" class="Show_when_view_more_than_line_">
        <span>Show when view more than line width</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Firefox Developer 91.0b2 (64-bit) OSX

**UPDATE:**
The issue was on some code on my side and not the browser.

Comment: I tried your snippet across Edge, Firefox, & Chrome and the same action is replicated across all three browsers

Comment: @BeerusDev Thank you. I'm going to post the page code. It works online for me too but it's not working locally from file protocol.

Comment: @BeerusDev I've posted the full page code

Comment: @BeerusDev It was some JavaScript code on my page that was causing the issue. The reason it would work in another browser was because JS was disabled in that browser.

Comment: @BeerusDev Error was in my code. The reason it worked in one browser and not the other was that javascript was enabled on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

there is an additional css styling you need to do for firefox

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  // put your styles here
}
```

or you can use this

```css
@media all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (max-width: 680px){
  // put your styles here
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use this. The top example I've not seen before. The bottom looks like it might work. I'll try wrapping it around the code I have. I added the full page code to the post.

Comment: add the codes to the css file you are using to style your html document